# Access base aligned to particular reference position

Tags: sam, pysam

**The short version**: If I have a SAM record, is there any simple way to retrieve the base aligned to a particular reference position without computing a pileup?

**The long version**: I'm using pysam to write some genotyping code. I have a BAM file with reads aligned to some amplicons. I'd now like to genotype a couple of positions of interest in each read while maintaining the phase information. For example, at amplicon 1, if read 1 has `A` for SNP1 and `T` at SNP2, then I want to report an `A,T` genotype for read 1 at amplicon 1.

The typical way to genotype SNPs of interest is to compute a pileup and look at all of the aligned bases position-by-position. The pysam API includes the following example of how to work with pileups.

```py
import pysam
samfile = pysam.AlignmentFile("ex1.bam", "rb" )
for pileupcolumn in samfile.pileup("chr1", 100, 120):
    print ("\ncoverage at base %s = %s" %
           (pileupcolumn.pos, pileupcolumn.n))
    for pileupread in pileupcolumn.pileups:
        if not pileupread.is_del and not pileupread.is_refskip:
            # query position is None if is_del or is_refskip is set.
            print ('\tbase in read %s = %s' %
                  (pileupread.alignment.query_name,
                   pileupread.alignment.query_sequence[pileupread.query_position]))

samfile.close()
```

However, I lose the phasing information if I analyze the data position-by-position. Is there any way to flip this example so that I'm iterating over reads in the outer loop, and then over positions in the inner loop? In other words, **if I'm iterating over reads, is there any simple way to retrieve the base aligned to a particular reference position *without* computing a pileup**?

As a potential solution, I've though about storing genotype information in a nested dictionary indexed first by read ID and then by position, but depending on coverage that could be incredibly memory intensive.

Comment: You can use `get_aligned_pairs()`; you'll get a list of tuples of `(position_in_query_sequence, position_in_reference_sequence)`

Comment: That's promising! It's been a hot second since I've worked on this code, but it looks like it could indeed allow me to keep phase information on a read-by-read basis. I'll try it out when I can.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`get_reference_positions()`](https://pysam.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pysam.AlignedSegment.get_reference_positions) function in pysam to get a vector of the positions. Searching that for your positions will allow you to output phased calls.

```
for read in bam.fetch(some_position):
    positions = read.get_reference_positions():
    if some_other_position in positions:
        idx = positions.index(some_position)
        idx2 = positions.index(some_other_positions)
        ... and so on...
```

That's not exactly correct syntax, but you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. When there are no insertions (`I` blocks) in the CIGAR, I can use `idx` and `idx2` to index directly in to `record.query_sequence` and get the base at the correct position. However, reads with insertions need additional operations to line up the `get_reference_positions()` indices with the `query_sequence` indices. So unless I'm missing something, it looks like there's a way to do this without computing a pileup...just not a simple way. :-)

Comment: I think you summarized it nicely, possible but not simple.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as you, and so I wrote my own code and sharing it here. No guarantee that it's bug-free ;-)

This code takes advantage of the cigar string. It returns None if the base has been deleted or clipped, or if the bam file did not store the sequence.

```
from typing import Optional
import pysam



def find_base_in_alignment(alignment: pysam.AlignedSegment,
                           pos: int, 
                           bam_stores_revcomp: bool = False) \ 
        -> Optional[str]:
    idx_q = 0
    idx_r = pos - alignment.reference_start
    if bam_stores_revcomp:
        seq = alignment.query_sequence
    else:
        seq = alignment.get_forward_sequence()
    
    if seq is None:
        return None
    
    for op, l in alignment.cigartuples:
        ref_consumed = op in {0, 2, 3, 7, 8}
        query_consumed = op in {0, 1, 4, 7, 8}
        
        if ref_consumed:
            idx_r -= l
        if query_consumed:
            idx_q += l
        
        if idx_r < 0:
            if query_consumed:
                # base is in query between idx_q-l , idx_q
                base = seq[idx_q + idx_r - 1]
                return base
            else:
                # position has been deleted
                return None
```

Let's say you want to genotype all reads by looking at the base at chromosome `chrom` and position `pos`:

```
bamfile = pysam.AlignmentFile(filename, "r" )
for alignment in bamfile.fetch(chrom, pos-1, pos+1):
    base = find_base_in_alignment(alignment, pos)
    # ... do something with it
```

Note that the parameter `bam_stores_revcomp` is important. Some aligners will store the original query sequence in the bam, and other aligners (like minimap2) will store the forward sequence (i.e. the reverse complement whenever a read was aligned to the reverse strand). If you use the former, set `bam_stores_revcomp` to `False`, otherwise set it to `True`

Comment: Hi, thank you for your code! I think it should be `if idx_r <= 0:` , then your code would report the exact same data as IGV, excluding insertions. Thank you!

Comment: this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is not [yet] a complete answer, but hopefully it helps get you on the right path.

I wrote [some code](https://gitlab.com/gringer/bioinfscripts/blob/master/sam2mapped.pl) to retrieve the subsequence from reads in a BAM file that are actually mapped to the reference, which required calculating mapped base locations. Here's a subsection of the code that does this (slightly paraphrased):

```
  my $refPos = $F[3];
  my $cigar = $F[5];
  $cigar =~ s/[0-9]S$//;
  my $seq = $F[9];
  my $qual = $F[10];
  my $startTrim = 0;
  my $matchLen = 0;
  while($cigar =~ s/^([0-9]+)([MIDNSHP=X])//){
    my $subLen = $1;
    my $op = $2;
    if($op eq "S"){
        $seq = substr($seq, $subLen);
        $qual = substr($qual, $subLen);
      }
    }
    if($op =~ /[M=XI]/){
      $matchLen += $subLen;
    }
  }
  $seq = substr($seq, 0, $matchLen + $addSeq);
  $qual = substr($qual, 0, $matchLen + $addSeq);
```

So, some things to take note of:

- The entire CIGAR string (excluding terminal soft clips) should be parsed up to the required base location
- Any soft clips at the start of the sequence need to be accounted for
- Only update the read location counter if there's a match, mismatch, or insertion