# Counting the co-occurrence of variants A and B in an aligned sequencing read

Tags: sam, samtools, mutations, variants

I need some help getting started on this project.

To simplify we want to be able to quantify the occurrence of 3 variants on each sequencing read in an alignment file as a proxy measurement for recombination.

The possible combinations we have are A, B or AB.

For example, variant A is at position 100 and variant B is at position 300 of the reference and AB would have both.

We have alignment files against a reference sequence, and then I get stuck. I could technically look by eye in tablet or IGV for example but is there a way to extract each read then query by expected base at the reference position then bin these reads into the categories; A, B, AB and unclassified then calculate the total occurrences of each?

Thanks for your time and suggestions!

Comment: You'll need to write something to do this, using pysam or a similar package.

Answer (score 1):

Related question: [Access base aligned to particular reference position](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/7401/access-base-aligned-to-particular-reference-position)

After an initial effort posted here, I ended up rewriting this and testing it a little, and posted the script [here](https://github.com/maximilianpress/teaching_code/blob/master/variant_cooccurrence.py). It still has some drawbacks (handling indels intelligently) but now it more or less works.